# How to round up to the next even number?

Tags: php, rounding

I want to round up to the next even whole number, with php.

Example:

- if 71 -> round up to 72
- if 33.1 -> round up to 34
- if 20.8 -> round up to 22

Comment: @amdixon  and others - how is this question TOO BROAD???? it is as specific as possible and I got the correct answer ... u guys need something more important to do than close old answered questions

Comment: No need to be harsh @Levchik, we are a few other people that feel this question deserves to stay opened. Also, closing old off-topic questions *is* an important step in keeping the quality of this site, so please don't regard errors such as this specific closure as ridiculous.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$num = ceil($input); // Round up decimals to an integer
if($num % 2 == 1) $num++; // If odd, add one
```

Test cases:

```
$tests = ['71' => '72', '33.1' => '34', '20.8' => '22'];
foreach($tests as $test => $expected) {
    $num = ceil($test);
    if($num % 2 == 1) $num++;
    echo "Expected: $expected, Actual: $num\n";
}
```

[Produces](https://3v4l.org/99vnY):

```
Expected: 72, Actual: 72
Expected: 34, Actual: 34
Expected: 22, Actual: 22
```

Comment: So if I have `$number` that = 71, how do I make it round up to 72 using your code above? Sorry, i'm not a programmer ...

Comment: Change every occurrence of `$num` and `$input` in my first code block to `$number` and you should be set.

Comment: yes - i did not see the first part before testing - thank you VERY much - you saved my @$$ :)

Comment: @RoofingCalculator Glad to hear it! Please consider accepting this post if it answered your question. Also, you should consider reviewing some of your older questions and accepting answers on those as well.

Comment: I just accepted - I had to wait like 3 minutes until I could accept ... my older posts - If I get answers that work I always accept ... again, THANKS A LOT!

Comment: btw ... i also need to figure out "ranges" but did not want to start another question - maybe you could help ... basically, I need something like this: if `$lengt` is =< 12 than use "12" ... if between 12 and 16 than use "16" and if > 16, then use 20 ... how do I code it without using LONG if/then statemtns?

Comment: @RoofingCalculator That's basically the same principle here, instead of rounding to the nearest 2s, you round to the nearest 4s.

Comment: @RoofingCalculator - You can [use this example](https://3v4l.org/TJtnm) to accomplish what you're looking for, I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = ceil($input); // Round up Floats to an integer
$num += $num % 2; // add $num modulo 2 remainder (is 1 if odd, 0 if even)
```

More options:

```
$num += $num % 2;       //next even
$num -= $num % 2;       //prev even
$num += ($num + 1) % 2; //next odd
$num -= ($num + 1) % 2; //prev odd
```